# UIImage size(width & Height) is decreasing after rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I am Rotating an UIImage According to a scale value.My Scale And Rotation are working well but the problem is  after rotating uiimage , the image  size (width & Height) is decreasing. Any idea how to solve the issue?
[Image before Rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixaJE.jpg)

[Image After Rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uTvg.jpg)

The code i am using :

```
 UIView *rotatedViewBox = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.image.size.width, self.image.size.height)];
    CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(self.lastContentOffset/5);
    rotatedViewBox.transform = t;
    CGSize rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size;

    // Create the bitmap context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize);
    CGContextRef bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
    CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, rotatedSize.width/2, rotatedSize.height/2);

    //   // Rotate the image context
    CGContextRotateCTM(bitmap, 5.0);

    // Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
    CGContextScaleCTM(bitmap, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(-self.image.size.width/2 , -self.image.size.height/2 , self.image.size.width, self.image.size.height), \[self.rotatedImage CGImage\]);

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    self.rotatedImage = newImage;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume your image was HxH in size. After 45 degrees (`M_PI/2` radians) rotation its going to be `sqrt(2)*H` x `sqrt(2)*H` in size. So you need bigger context in order to fit rotated image. Otherwise the corners of an image will be cut off. Also you will need bigger `UIImageView` in order to fit bigger image. Otherwise it's going to be autoscaled to the `UIImageView` size.

Comment: Thanks mate,i have changed the context size,  it  worked @s0urcer

Comment: Hello @InvictusCody what do you mean by changing the context size? Can you please add the new code?

Comment: @tejasreevangapalli, I had to use a custom Height and Width for rotated image , not the image.size.width, mage.size.height.